# NuGet PackageManager.InstallPackageAsync() throws NullReferenceException

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm working on a plug-in management system built on top of Nuget similar to Chocolatey, PowerShell Gallery etc.

I want to use the newer [V3 libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Packaging/) rather then the deprecated [V2 Nuget.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/) library used by Chocolatey. However, the amount of abstraction and the lack of documentation in the V3 libraries is becoming a serious challenge for me. I'm still failing to get simple prototype working that will download and extract a package.

Here's my test code:
https://github.com/ericanastas/nuget-packagemanagment-test

```
       private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var curDir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                ISettings settings = Settings.LoadSpecificSettings(curDir, Settings.DefaultSettingsFileName);

                List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>> resourceProviders = new List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>>();
                resourceProviders.AddRange(NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());  // Add v3 API support
                IPackageSourceProvider packageSourceProvider = new PackageSourceProvider(settings);
                SourceRepositoryProvider sourceRepositoryProvider = new SourceRepositoryProvider(packageSourceProvider, resourceProviders);

                string projectRoot = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("ProjectRoot");
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(projectRoot)) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(projectRoot);

                FolderNuGetProject nuGetProject = new FolderNuGetProject(projectRoot);

                string packagesFolderPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("Packages");
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(packagesFolderPath)) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(packagesFolderPath);

                NuGetPackageManager packageManager = new NuGetPackageManager(sourceRepositoryProvider, settings, packagesFolderPath)
                {
                    PackagesFolderNuGetProject = nuGetProject
                };

                bool allowPrereleaseVersions = true;
                bool allowUnlisted = true;
                DependencyBehavior dependencyBehavior = DependencyBehavior.Lowest;

                ResolutionContext resolutionContext = new ResolutionContext(
                         dependencyBehavior, allowPrereleaseVersions, allowUnlisted, VersionConstraints.None);

                INuGetProjectContext projectContext = new ConsoleProjectContext(NullLogger.Instance);

                IEnumerable<SourceRepository> primarySourceRepositories = sourceRepositoryProvider.GetRepositories();

                //packageIdentity
                string packageId = "Newtonsoft.Json";
                string packageVersion = "12.0.3";
                PackageIdentity packageIdentity = new PackageIdentity(packageId, new NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion(packageVersion));

                var installPackageAsyncTask = packageManager.InstallPackageAsync(packageManager.PackagesFolderNuGetProject,
                    packageIdentity, resolutionContext, projectContext,
                    primarySourceRepositories, Array.Empty<SourceRepository>(), CancellationToken.None);

                installPackageAsyncTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("error.txt"))
                {
                    sw.Write(exp.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And here's the `NullReferenceException` that is thrown at the end when I try to call `InstallPackageAsync()`

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.FolderNuGetProject.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<InstallPackageAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteInstallAsync>d__85.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<InstallPackageAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<InstallPackageAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at NugetTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Git\5ec64809061464dc19a1d4e39961c565\NugetTest\Program.cs:line 66
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also currently muddling through this. I've found the source of [this repository](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/bb2b3bfec842fb11eeb96dcc0840dd738f43bc8e/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Commands/InstallCommand.cs) to be useful.

To get your sample code working, change the `projectContext` initialization to this:

```cs
var clientPolicyContext = ClientPolicyContext.GetClientPolicy(settings, NullLogger.Instance);
INuGetProjectContext projectContext = new ConsoleProjectContext(NullLogger.Instance)
{
    PackageExtractionContext = new PackageExtractionContext(
        PackageSaveMode.Defaultv3,
        PackageExtractionBehavior.XmlDocFileSaveMode,
        clientPolicyContext,
        NullLogger.Instance
    )
};
```

In production code, you'll probably want to use a real logger instead of the `NullLogger`.